# South-west US/Hawaii Volleyball fun tournament in September

Tags: usa, activities, outdoor-activities

My girlfriend and I are travelling the US in september. There is no schedule yet, but we would rather see the west-side of the US or Hawaii than east/mid, because both of us have already been there.

From our past vacation experience we found out, that both of us don't like "being passive" all the time, like doing city tours or hanging at the beach constantly. As both of us like playing volleyball, we thought a common mixed-tournament or something similar might be a cool activity.

Now when I'm looking on the web for something like this, I mostly find things like tournaments of active university leagues or so. We'd also be fine with playing just with random people at the beach, but we dislike the thought of people interrupting mid-game asking to join or leaving the court.

As it's quite hard to find something reliable, does anyone have suggestions or experience? Especially Hawaii would be perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience some beach hotels in Hawaii and Mexico organize daily beach volleyball tourneys. Unfortunately they don't usually publish their activity schedules online, and even if it's on their activity schedule it doesn't mean enough players show up for a game. Your best bet will be to contact the hotel directly and ask for the activities desk.

In a recent stay at the [Hyatt Ziva Los Cabos](http://loscabos.ziva.hyatt.com/en/hotel/home.html) there was a competitive beach volleyball tourney every day at 4pm.

In SoCal there are of course many public courts that are used day-round. I recommend checking out various [meet-ups](http://www.meetup.com/topics/beach-volleyball/us/ca/venice/) and clubs for options. One could possibly build a road trip around various beaches in Southern California.